# How to add multiple pictures in Python ebay sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api, trading

Here is my setup:

> Python 3.4
>
> Using the Trading API
>
> Attempting to call eBay's "VerifyAddItem"

I marked where I get the Error, in `PicURL`, and I'm trying to post multiple pictures with multiple URLs.  I'm currently just trying out two pictures let's say `http://i.ebayimg.com/picture1` and `http://i.ebayimg.com/picture2`.  (I realize that these are not real pictures, but that's not part of the problem I'm having)

The eBay API Documentations states `To specify multiple pictures, send each URL in a separate, PictureDetails.PictureURL element. The first URL passed in will be the Gallery image and appears on the View Item page.` So I tried passing both of the following lines to no avail:

```
"PictureDetails": {"PictureURL": ["http://i.ebayimg.com/picture1",
                                  "http://i.ebayimg.com/picture2"]}
```

and

```
"PictureDetails": [{"PictureURL": "http://i.ebayimg.com/picture1"},
                   {"PictureURL": "http://i.ebayimg.com/picture2"}]
```

I get the following errors from eBay's connection, respectively:

```
VerifyAddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 37, Input data is invalid. 
Input data for tag <Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL[2]> is invalid or missing. Please 
check API documentation.
```

and

```
VerifyAddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 37, Input data is invalid. 
Input data for tag <Item.PictureDetails[2].PictureURL> is invalid or missing. Please 
check API documentation.
```

Unfortunately, I have run out of ideas.  Please help! Here is the full dictionary, don't worry about the logic, as I have verified that everything else works fine.

```
api = Trading(config_file="ebay.yaml", warnings=False)

    myitem = {
        "Item": {
            "Title": Title,
            "Description": Description,
            "PrimaryCategory": {"CategoryID": p.CategoryValue},
            "StartPrice": str(p.Price_sbox.value()),
            "CategoryMappingAllowed": "true",
            "Country": "US",
            "ConditionID": CatID,
            "ConditionDescription": p.CondDetail_tedit.toPlainText(),
            "Currency": "USD",
            "DispatchTimeMax": "1",
            "ListingDuration": "GTC",
            "ListingType": "FixedPriceItem",
            "PaymentMethods": "PayPal",
            "PayPalEmailAddress": PayPal,
            #############################
            ###This is where I get the Error
            #############################
            "PictureDetails": PicURL,
            "PostalCode": ZipCode,
            "Quantity": str(p.Quantity_sbox.value()),
            "ReturnPolicy": {
                "ReturnsAcceptedOption": "ReturnsAccepted",
                "RefundOption": "MoneyBack",
                "Description": "14 days money back, you pay return shipping",
                "ReturnsWithinOption": "Days_14",
                "ShippingCostPaidByOption": "Buyer" },
            "ShippingDetails": {
                "ShippingType": "Calculated",
                "PaymentInstructions": "1 business days of handling time, usually shipped next day. Make sure your address is correct, especially when shipping to foreign countries.",
                "ShippingServiceOptions": {
                    "FreeShipping": FreeShip,
                    "ShippingService": ShipService
                    },
                "CalculatedShippingRate": {"OriginatingPostalCode": ZipCode} },
            "ShippingPackageDetails": {
                "MeasurementUnit": "English",
                "WeightMajor": str(p.WeightLbs_sbox.value()),
                "WeightMinor": str(p.WeightOz_sbox.value()),
                "PackageDepth": str(p.DimensionH_sbox.value()),
                "PackageLength": str(p.DimensionL_sbox.value()),
                "PackageWidth": str(p.DimensionW_sbox.value()),
                "ShippingPackage": "PackageThickEnvelope"},
            "ShipToLocations": "Worldwide",
            "Site": "US",
            "SKU": p.ItemID_ledit.text() } }
    IntShip = []
    boolint = False
    if(p.IntShip1_chbox.isChecked()):
        IntShip.append('USPSPriorityMailInternational')
        boolint = True
    if(p.IntShip2_chbox.isChecked()):
        IntShip.append('USPSPriorityMailInternationalLargeFlatRateBox')
        boolint = True
    if(boolint):
        myitem['Item']['ShippingDetails']['ShippingServiceOptions']['InternationalShippingServiceOption'] = IntShip
    if(p.BestOffer_chbox.isChecked()):
        myitem['Item']['BestOfferDetails'] = {'BestOfferEnabled': 'true'}

    #print(myitem)
    api.execute('VerifyAddItem', myitem)
    print("%s" % api.response.content)
                
except ConnectionError as e:
    for node in api.response.dom().findall('ErrorCode'):
        print("error code: %s" % node.text)
    if 37 in api.response_codes():
        print("Invalid data in request")
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well nevermind... I feel dumb... Since I'm still working in sandbox, I'm passing test photos where some of the URLs in the list `PicURL` do not point to a valid photo.

If anyone else gets these errors, the first format is the correct one:

```
"PictureDetails": {"PictureURL": ["http://i.ebayimg.com/picture1",
                                  "http://i.ebayimg.com/picture2"]}
```